# Radio Input gets unchecked after jQuery html operation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button, checked

I'm getting an extremely weird error. My radio button gets unchecked after doing the following operations:

```
    var $page = $('[data-shortcode-page="' + shortcode + '"]', $webrock).html();

    //CHECKED
    console.log($('[data-shortcode-page="' + shortcode + '"] :checked', $webrock).length) 
    $('.webrock-page-content', $addPage).replaceWith($page);
    //UNCHECKED
    console.log($('[data-shortcode-page="' + shortcode + '"] :checked', $webrock).length)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mVB2q/1/

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd imagine it has something to do with `.replaceWith($page)`.

Comment: Can you add some fiddle ?

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mVB2q/1/

Comment: how can we reproduce the error? this code should be called when you select an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are cloning a radio group with the same name. You need to update the name of the cloned radio group. Here is a simple solution where I am hardcoding in "test1" for the new group name, but you may want to modify it to fit your needs:

```
var shortcode = 'object';        

var $page = $('[data-shortcode-page="' + shortcode + '"]');

console.log($('[data-shortcode-page="' + shortcode + '"] :checked').length);

//after cloning the radio buttons, find radio buttons and update the name attribute.
$('.webrock-page-content').html($page.clone().find("input[type='radio']").attr("name", "test1").end().html());
console.log($('[data-shortcode-page="' + shortcode + '"] :checked').length);
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mVB2q/2/).

Comment: Hi Patrick, I've also thought about fixing it this way. I know the reason why it's not working now. Thank you!